# Cursor not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using cursor in ms sql server

```
DECLARE @LineOfAuthoritySubString varchar(100);
declare @tbProductId int;
declare @tbLineOfAuthorityId int;

 DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
 SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
 FOR
 Select TempLineOfAuthority FROM #tbTempLineOfAuthority
 OPEN @MyCursor
 FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
 INTO @LineOfAuthoritySubString  
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 Set @tbLineOfAuthorityId = (Select LineOfAuthority
 from tbLineOfAuthority where LineOfAuthorityX = @LineOfAuthorityNameSubString);

  INSERT INTO tbProductLineOfAuthority(ProductId, LineOfAuthortyId)   
  VALUES(@tbProductId, @tbLineOfAuthorityId);

  FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
  INTO @LineOfAuthoritySubString
  END
  CLOSE @MyCursor
  DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```

It's not working. It is assigning null value to the variable @tbLineOfAuthorityId.

Comment: where is `declare @tbLineOfAuthorityId int` ???

Comment: I have already mentioned all the variables. Some of the declaration of variables are omitted in the question only

Comment: @user2315555 - so what is the use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting cursor value in  `@LineOfAuthoritySubString`   and in **where condition** `@LineOfAuthorityNameSubString` variable is used

Both variable name is mismatched.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @LineOfAuthoritySubString
```

IN above you are fetching value in variable @LineOfAuthoritySubString .

```
 Set @tbLineOfAuthorityId = (Select LineOfAuthority  from tbLineOfAuthority where LineOfAuthorityX = @LineOfAuthorityNameSubString);
```

But when you are selecting from table tbLineOfAuthority, observe the variable you are using in where query.

It should be **@LineOfAuthoritySubString** and not  **@LineOfAuthorityNameSubString**

**pleae try below edited query if it works.**

```
DECLARE @LineOfAuthoritySubString varchar(100);
declare @tbProductId int;
declare @tbLineOfAuthorityId int;

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
Select TempLineOfAuthority FROM #tbTempLineOfAuthority
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @LineOfAuthoritySubString  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Set @tbLineOfAuthorityId = (Select LineOfAuthority
from tbLineOfAuthority where LineOfAuthorityX = @LineOfAuthoritySubString);

INSERT INTO tbProductLineOfAuthority(ProductId, LineOfAuthortyId)   
VALUES(@tbProductId, @tbLineOfAuthorityId);

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @LineOfAuthoritySubString
END
CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
```

Comment: I am confused... please explain